# Is there a way to track clicks on my Google Adsense ads?

Tags: javascript, events, adsense

I have a page with Google Adsense ads. Is there any way to track when a user clicks on one of these these ads?

I thought about adding a javascript onclick of some sort, perhaps one that logs the click and then passes on to the ad. But I'm not sure how this would work, is it possible?

Thanks for any assistance!

dylan

Comment: Why you want to do this when you can get a lots of information using Adsense features. See http://adsense.blogspot.com/2009/04/analytics-integration-for-all.html

Comment: I'd like to be able to A/B Test layout changes. I don't think Adsense Analytics lets me do that because I can't send in a field to specify which version is being used. Right?  (They support channel ids, but that's for groups of ads - not layout changes)